# Filter / Iterate a List by values inside List C#

Tags: c#, list, loops, sorting, filter

Hello I am using c# in ASP.NET MVC Web.

I have a list of object that contains different different data inside example:

```
List<One> obj = new List<One>();
obj[0].studentname = "rahul";
obj[0].rolenumber = "20";

obj[1].studentname = "padhiyar";
obj[1].rolenumber = "74";

...
...
...

obj[max].studentname = "lastname of the student";
obj[max].rolenumber = "his / her roll number";
```

I want to iterate this list and get another list which is sorted by role number which is string and some object may not have role number inside so how may I do this?

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: Those who don't know the answer please do not mark it down. If any problem say it in comment nut just mark it down. thanks.

Comment: LINQ. You can handle via it

Comment: @onur I don't know how and **rolenumber** is string so how can I do that using linq

Comment: What's the structure of `another list` you mentioned?

Comment: The same list as I can store also in **var** too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case you will have all students without parsebar rolnumber on the top, if you do want to have them in the bottom, change `Int32.MinValue` to `Int32.MaxValue`

```
var sorted = obj.OrderBy(x =>
{
    int res;
    bool parsed = Int32.TryParse(x.rolenumber, out res);
    return parsed? res: Int32.MinValue;
});
```